# Existence of a continuously differentiable function from the projection of a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $V$ be an open convex set of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and let $U$ be the projection of $V$ onto $\mathbb{R}^n$ - i.e. the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that there is some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(x,y) \in V$. It follows that $U$ is an open convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - however i have difficulties in understanding the validity of the following statement (which is used in the proof of theorem 10.38 in the book "Analysis" of Rudin):

There is a continuously differentiable (real-valued) function $\alpha$ defined on $U$ such that $(x,\alpha(x)) \in V$ holds for any choice of $x \in U$.

(The proof would be trivial for special cases of convex sets - like rectangles. However i do not see how this could help in proving the result for general convex sets)

Comment: At that point, are partitions of unity available?

Comment: thanks for your hint and answer. Yes partitions of unity are available at that point. So i guess the first step would be to construct locally a differentiable function around any point - however I do not see how to ensure the consistency of such an approach when two regions corresponding to two different points overlap - i.e. i do not know how to get a globally defined function from these local results. But maybe i miss a point.

Comment: If $(x,y) \in V$, then, since $V$ is open, there is a neighbourhood $W_x$ of $x$ such that $W_x \times \{y\} \subset V$. Take a partition of unity subordinate to the open cover $\{ W_x : x \in U\}$ (or a locally finite refinement of that), and glue things together with that partition of unity. Why is the convexity of $V$ relevant?

Comment: As a nice example: If we take $V=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<x,y,x+y<1\right\}$ (the interior of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, then $\alpha$ cannot be linear (or affine, to be more precise).

Comment: Apologies for the late question. What is meant by "construct locally a differentiable function around any point"? I truly don't even see where to begin to do that. Moreover, the functions which form a partition of unity are continuous (Rudin Thm 10.8), whereas we require a function that is continuously differentiable. How is this extra smoothness achieved? If anyone feels so gracious, I sure wouldn't mind another hint.